# Web assembly cvtColor not working properly on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, webassembly, emscripten

OpenCV cvtColor seems to not work properly on iOS with web assembly. When calling cvtColor two times in a row, the second run delivers wrong results. Using the following code snippet I can reproduce the issue:

```
void testCvtImage()
{
  cv::Mat result(2048, 1365, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(125, 170, 255, 255));
  cv::Mat m;
  cv::cvtColor(result, m, cv::ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);
  std::cout << "Dimensions of m: " << m.cols << "x" << m.rows << " pixelvalue:" << static_cast<int>(m.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,0)[0]) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Starting gray image testing" << std::endl;
  cv::Mat grayRGB(2048, 1365, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));
  cv::Mat grayRGBA;
  cv::cvtColor(grayRGB, grayRGBA, cv::ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

  for (int row=0; row<grayRGB.rows; ++row) {
    for (int col=0; col<grayRGB.cols; ++col) {
      auto v1 = grayRGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(row, col);
      auto v2 = grayRGBA.at<cv::Vec4b>(row, col);
      if (v1[0] != v2[0] || v1[1] != v2[1] || v1[2] != v2[2]) {
        std::cout << "Non matching pixel found!" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Finished gray image testing" << std::endl;
}
```

Some details of my build setup:

- Conan 1.60.0
- Emscripten 3.1.31
- OpenCV 4.5.5

I was able to reproduce the issue on multiple different iOS devices in Chrome as well as in Safari. I didn't manage to reproduce it on any desktop browser though.

On iOS devices, the `std::cout << "Non matching pixel found!" << std::endl;` output was shown thousands of times. When visually inspecting the faulty converted image, it had regular vertical green stripes all over the image. When inspecting the RGB values, it showed that all faulty pixels have the RGB value (0, 128, 0, 255).

Does someone have a hint on why this could happen?

Edit (07/24/2023): I was able to reproduce this issue among different iOS devices which had iOS 15.5.1 (c) installed. Just tested it on one device where iOS 16.6 developer beta version is installed and the problem is gone there. So, it seems that this could just be an iOS bug that is solved starting from iOS 16.6.